# How to efficiently report large amount of UI bugs?

Tags: bug-report, efficiency

I just got the first drop of a new component with significant UI content. Playing with it for less than 30 minutes I already identified 10 bugs. Writing these down in an eMail occurred while doing the exploratory testing (E.g. it's part of the 30 minutes). If I now start reporting them one by one in Jira, it will probably take another hour.

Any suggestions how to be one one hand meticulous (report bugs in the system) and on the other hand not to lose so much time?

My initial thought is to declare a certain period of time after a new UI release as "integration time" during which we report bugs in a less formal way (e.g. email). But I can see the associated problem (e.g. other testers won't have visibility to issues already reported).

Thoughts? Ideas? Do we just bite the bullet and report formally?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options on how you report bugs and they all have benefits and downsides.

1. Use a bug template. This is a standard approach to reporting bugs in Jira or other similar tools. Copy and paste the template and fill it out appropriately. (You didn't say in the question if you're doing this or not; hopefully, you are). Does this still take time? Yes, but it's better than not using a template.  The benefit of this is that all your bugs are formatted the same, which allows all the devs, designers, PMs, etc to quickly understand the issue you are reporting. And as you said, the downside is it takes time. To me, the time it takes is negligible as the time it takes for you to write it allows you to fully understand all the implications of the bug. Adding bugs to Jira allows for your work contributions to be known, searchable, triagable, etc.
2. Only take and send screenshots or videos of the bugs to the developers. This is quicker and you can still annotate the screenshots with some quick notes or narrate the video with information.
3. Pair-testing. This is often an overlooked method, but it comes in handy with the situation you are in. Since this is a new feature, maybe it is not quite understood what the requirements are for the developer or what the finished project will be. Maybe you're on a quick timeline to finish. Regardless of the reasons, now that you have found lots of bugs, have the developer physically sit with you (or remotely on a screen share) and you can show them each and every bug. Ask them how they want you to share the bug details with them after that. Or better if they are simple bugs, they can fix the bugs right then and there beside you. Then, they can show you the fix for a quick review. Keep repeating this until all the bugs you found are fixed!

There are more options to consider, though, these are the most popular. For you, I'd recommend doing the pair-testing option as it's quite efficient!

Comment: Thanks Lee. Using a bug template is already in place. In fact... one oi the reasons it takes MORE time to report a bug is that we have a template... because now you need to be meticulous and fill in the details...  Just to think how to phrase the bug Title (or "Summary" in Jira speak) takes time, since you want to pass a lot of information in one concise line. 

Option 2 is the easiest, with the down side that there is no record, no tracking etc. 

Option 3 works during Integration since a lot of bugs come up, many of which can be fixed with a simple and fast code change.

Comment: +1 for pairing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've understood your question. You are facing a challenge that many SDETs and QA professionals encounter: the trade-off between speed and meticulousness in bug reporting.

You may consider to use below template:

```
Bug ID: [Unique Identifier]
Title: [Brief Description]
Severity: [Critical/Major/Minor/Trivial]
Environment: [Where it was found]
Steps to Reproduce: 
  1.
  2.
  3.
Expected Result: 
Actual Result:
Attachments: [Screenshots, logs, etc.]
```

Comment: A classic and useful template.  Reminds me of this [article that I've used with many teams.](https://testlio.com/blog/the-ideal-bug-report/)

Answer (score 1):

To report multiple defects efficiently we can user automation strategy by using automation tools like report Rortal,Selenium Webdriver and Third-eye AI.

Report portal help us to identify defect easily using screenshot and it can directly report those defect in jira without any human intervention.

Further, Third Eye and other automation like selenium we can use Jira API's to report the defect after execution of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Many [software qa consulting](https://www.qasource.com/qa-consulting-and-analysis-services) services personnel prefer the following tools and approaches to efficiently report large UI bugs:

1. Cypress: A JavaScript end-to-end testing framework that supports automatic screenshots and video recording, useful for documenting UI bugs.
2. Applitools: It provides visual testing tools to automatically detect and report visual UI differences between baseline and current states. It's commonly used for catching visual bugs across different browsers.
3. BugBash: It's specifically designed for bug reporting and management, allowing users to easily capture screenshots, annotate them, and provide detailed descriptions of issues.